# How to get Classpath for an EAR deployed in WebLogic Server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I have an application deployed as an EAR in WebLogic 10.3.2 version. I am working on some implementations where I got to scan all of the .jar files in classpath.

At Runtime, when i call `System.getProperty("java.class.path");`, It returns me the WebLogic bootstrap classpath, NOT the one which my application is using within the EAR file.

Is there any way to the get the classpath which is being used by EAR file? I mean which is defined inside META-INF/MANIFEST.txt file.

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");`

Or, if you need to load stuff, you should take a look into `java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();` and/or `java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will give it a try and get back to you in case any issue. Regards Raj

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use getClassLoader() method and need to provide the "/" before the file name you are accessing

```
this.getClass().getResource("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```